# Some good things can come in threes, I hope you find my riddle one of these

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, humor

> My prefix is delicious
>   My infix relates to switches
>   My suffix is how some children do their dishes.
>   And my whole can lead you to great riches!

My sincere compliments to Riley :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> **pioneer**.

My prefix is delicious

> The math constant **pi** is commonly punned with *pie*, which is delicious.

My infix relates to switches

> **On** is one possible state of an on-off switch.

My suffix is how some children do their dishes.

> **Ne'er** is short for never, which is jokingly how often some children do dishes.

And my whole can lead you to great riches!

> To **pioneer** is to innovate in ways that can lead to success.